# Using find command to count certain type of executables

Tags: unix, find

I'm trying to use Unix's find command to count the number of executable files in a directory of a certain type, namely Solaris(MSB) executable's. I know I can get the count of all executable files in this directory fairly easy with

```
find . -type f -perm -u+rx | wc -l
```

however this doesn't count Solaris(MSB) executable files exclusively. I thought to remedy this I would just throw in a `-name` flag, something like this.

```
find . -name "sparc*" -type f -perm -u+rx | wc -l
```

This will correctly return that there are 6 only if I remove the part of the command that specify's that they need to be executable, if I keep this part of the command it returns a count of 0 which is "wrong". When I look at the `ls -l` command below I can see that these files are executable I think? or that they are pointing to an executable? This might be the root of the problem.

```
ls -l    
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root   other          57 Jul 15  2005 sparc-sun-solaris2.9-c++ -> /usr/local/gnu/pkg/gcc-3.3.6/bin/sparc-sun-solaris2.9-c++*
```

Any insight is appreciated.

Comment: correct. Its pointing to an executable.  https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/soft-hard-links-unixlinux/

Comment: I see I see. Is there anyway I can denote somewhere in the command to instead consider the hard link as opposed to the file name? @al76

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
find -L . -type f -perm -u+rx | wc -l
```

or

```
find -L . -name "sparc*" -type f -perm -u+rx | wc -l
```

or whatever conditions you need.

Option `-L` instructs `find` to follow symbolic links instead of processing the link itself. (see e.g. https://www.unix.com/man-page/posix/1p/find/)

For example with the symbolic link

```
sparc-sun-solaris2.9-c++ -> /usr/local/gnu/pkg/gcc-3.3.6/bin/sparc-sun-solaris2.9-c++*
```

`find` should behave as if the file `/usr/local/gnu/pkg/gcc-3.3.6/bin/sparc-sun-solaris2.9-c++` would be directly located at `sparc-sun-solaris2.9-c++`

If your `find` doesn't support option `-L` you can try `-follow` like this:

```
find . -follow -name "sparc*" -type f -perm -u+rx | wc -l
```

Comment: Interesting, I actually didn't know unix file systems have hard/soft link capabilities. Could I then append the -name flag to the command and do something like, `find -L . -name "*sparc*" -type f -perm -u+rx | wc -l` because the command above now counts all symbolically linked executable's, not just solaris one's

Comment: I have seen your edit. After testing the command provided I'm still getting a return of 0 count. Does specifying the `-L` not force `-name` to search for the `/usr/local/gnu/pkg/gcc-3.3.6/bin/sparc-sun-solaris2.9-c++` but instead search for `sparc-sun-solaris2.9-c++` which isn't an executable?

Comment: I'm not on a system where I could test my proposed commands. Try the command step by step, e.g. `find -L .`, `find -L . -type f`, `find -L . -type f -perm -u+rx` and compare with the output of the corresponding command without `-L`.

Comment: Will do, thank you for your help I will select this as the answer and keep trying things.

Comment: I just feel like i'm missing something, even when I try to do the command step by step startign with `find -L .` all i get in return is `find: path-list predicate-list
` any ideas? @Bodo

Comment: Does your `find` support the `-L` option?

Comment: If the Solaris `find` doesn't support `-L`, maybe you could install GNU `find`

Comment: Unfortunately I don't have administrative privileges in this system as I'm using an environment provided by this workshop I'm taking.

Comment: After playing with it more using, `find /usr/local/bin 1 -name "*sparc*" -type l -ls` gives me all 6 solaris files however, only 5 of them point to an executable.

Comment: Yes, it is definitely getting the right output result. Thank you for your help, again.